# Spring Test : why cannot access application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I'm building an extremly easy Spring Boot application. It has no code, just a simple test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @Value("${my.key}")
    private String key;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

`my.key` is defined inside `src/main/resources/application.properties` (in `main/` not `test/`)

The test doesn't pass because cannot find `my.key` property (but if I put this property inside `src/test/resources/application.properties` it works)

I'm sure I have seen plenty of Spring Boot applications where test classes read properties from `/main/resources/application.properties`

But here it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also add a `application.properties` file inside `src/test/resources`, this will "override" the one in `src/main/resources`, and hence none of the keys you define in your "production" properties file will be seen.

So either remove your `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` to use your property file in `src/main/resources` or define your values there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@TestPropertySource** to override the location of your application.properties.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class MyTest {

}
```

For further help on how to use it, please check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source)